# Unable to bind data to XTemplate

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to display data in a Panel with this simple example with Sencha Touch 2, but it's not working :

```javascript
var planetEarth = {
    name: "Earth",
    mass: 1.00
};

var planetInfo = new Ext.XTemplate("<h2>{name}</h2>mass: {mass}");

var profile = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
  fullscreen: true,
  xtype: 'panel',
  layout: 'fit',
  data : planetEarth,
  tpl: planetInfo
});

Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(profile);
```

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work for me: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#KxGHo

[edit] To clarify, you need to wait until the document has finished loading before defining and executing any code that's used to build the user interface. Place your code in the application 'launch' method.

Comment: Indeed, the problem was because the document had not finished loading. Anyway, I solved it by using setData() and setTpl() after the declaration of my panel and it worked.